# Prevent Screen flickering when opening a second Workbook (same instance)

Tags: excel, vba

**Prefix**: My code opens an external workbook that has a DB inside with some information which should not be visible to the entire organization. I am able to open the external workbook, and retrieve all the data from the `PivotTable` successfully.

**Problem**: When my code runs, the screen flickers for ~ 0.5 seconds to show the other workbook.

**Goal**: not to have any flickering on the screen when switching between workbooks.

**My Code** (relevant section):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetBudgetData_fromPivotTable(Budget_ShtName As String, Budget_PvtName As String)

Dim BudgetWB                            As Workbook
Dim PvtTbl                              As PivotTable
Dim pvtFld                              As PivotField
Dim strPvtFld                           As String
Dim prjName                             As String

' ****** This is the Section I am trying to prevent from the screen to flicker ******
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' read budget file parameters
Set BudgetWB = Workbooks.Open(BudgetFile_Folder & BudgetFile_wbName)

BudgetWB.Windows(1).Visible = False
OriginalWB.Activate ' <-- this is the original workbook that is calling the routine

Set PvtTbl = BudgetWB.Worksheets(Budget_ShtName).PivotTables(Budget_PvtName)

' a lot of un-relevant code line

BudgetWB.Close (False)  ' close budget file
OriginalWB.Activate

' restore settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a workaround idea - how about activating a big modeless userform? Then the flickering would stay in the background.

Comment: Or another idea - set the whole Excel application invisible, while opening the BudgetWB - `application.Visible = false` and then set it back.

Comment: @Vityata i prefer not to open a second Excel instance

Comment: @Mat'sMug any ideas ?

Comment: @Jeeped any ideas ?

Comment: @ShaiRado if they have not commented on this thread putting `@` in front of their names will not call them.  And, sorry this is beyond me.  I have been lurking in hopes to learn something.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, on other users PC sometimes it hangs for a few seconds

Comment: @ShaiRado - you do not open a second Excel instance, you simply make  `application.visible = false` and it is the current instance. Write it before `Set BudgetWB = Workbooks.Open(BudgetFile_Folder & BudgetFile_wbName)` and then after `BudgetWB.Windows(1).Visible = False` turn it back to visible.

Comment: @Vityata Tried your idea, unfortunately the entire Excel is off now for ~ 0.5 seconds, and another windows application is visible (my Desktop or PowerPoint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To minimize screen flicker, I think the following should work; it is adding in the additional step of hiding the ActiveWindow once ScreenUpdating has been turned off to allow the workbook to be opened and hidden before resetting the visibility levels. When I tried it, the ribbon appears to deactivate and activate, but the spreadsheet stayed flicker-free. Not sure if this is enough of an improvement for you...

```
Public Sub GetBudgetData_fromPivotTable(Budget_ShtName As String, Budget_PvtName As String)

    Dim BudgetWB                            As Workbook
    Dim PvtTbl                              As PivotTable
    Dim pvtFld                              As PivotField
    Dim strPvtFld                           As String
    Dim prjName                             As String

    ' ****** This is the Section I am trying to prevent from the screen to flicker ******
    Dim wbWindow As Window: Set wbWindow = ActiveWindow
    ' Freeze current screen
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wbWindow.Visible = False

    ' read budget file parameters
    Set BudgetWB = Workbooks.Open(BudgetFile_Folder & BudgetFile_wbName)
    BudgetWB.Windows(1).Visible = False

    ' Reset current screen
    wbWindow.Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    OriginalWB.Activate ' <-- this is the original workbook that is calling the routine

    Set PvtTbl = BudgetWB.Worksheets(Budget_ShtName).PivotTables(Budget_PvtName)

    ' a lot of un-relevant code line

    BudgetWB.Close (False)  ' close budget file
    OriginalWB.Activate

    ' restore settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is an improvement, the scrren still filcker, but it is reduced. Any ideas how to eliminate the flickering entirely ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible from the trials and research I've done. I have found that disabling events before opening the file tends to shorten the flicker time though; (and using this preferentially over setting the activewindow as hidden gave me the best result)

Comment: Thanks :) it didn't remove all the flickering, but it has reduced the "hanging" screen a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Another work around, that would work, if you like it. The idea is that you copy the sheet with the pivot table in your workbook and you work from there. Make the sheet hidden and once you are ready with the work - delete it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportSheet()

    Dim wbBk            As Workbook
    Dim wsSht           As Worksheet
    Dim sImportFile     As String
    Dim sFile           As String
    Dim sThisBk         As Workbook
    Dim vfilename       As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set sThisBk = ActiveWorkbook
    sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", Title:="Open Workbook")

    vfilename = Split(sImportFile, "\")
    sFile = vfilename(UBound(vfilename))
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=sImportFile

    Set wbBk = Workbooks(sFile)
    If SheetExists("MyPivotData") Then
        Set wsSht = wbBk.Sheets("MyPivotData")
        wsSht.Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyPivotData").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If

    'do your work
    'then delete the added sheet

    wbBk.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Private Function SheetExists(sWSName As String) As Boolean

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets(sWSName)
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True

End Function
```