# Is there a way to prevent screen flashing when turning ScreenUpdating back on?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am building a production dashboard which includes a "Dark Theme" option where the design will change to a theme with dark colors. When the Macro that does it (~1700 lines, roughly 250 Shapes affected) has not been triggered in a while, the screen changes in a single instance. When triggering multiple times in a row, there is a visible "process" of shapes changing to the dark theme (macro is still finishing in <1 sec.). Is there a way to prevent this?

Options I tried already:

- Saving workbook in between (makes the macro unnecessary slow)
- DoEvents (seems to have no effect)

Code:

Main Switch:

```
Sub EnableDarkTheme()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    MenuOptions.Range("B11").Value = "On"
    
    Call EnableDarkThemeBasicInAllSheets
    
    Call EnableDarkThemeInFrontpage
    Call EnableDarkThemeInDashboard
    Call EnableDarkThemeInWegdiagramme
    Call EnableDarkThemeInAliasstruktur
    
    Call SetDarkThemeSettings("On", MenuOptions.Range("B2").Value)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Example from the called Subs (done for each Shape that has to be changed in the targeted worksheets):

```
With Frontpage
        With .Shapes.Range(Array("Background_Basic_Functions"))
            .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
            .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0.25
            
            With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(256, 256, 256)
            End With
        End With
        
        ...
```

Comment: You could try making the application window invisible during the process and between setting screenupdating to False and True. Just make sure you have error control to reset visibility in the event of an error. Based on the answer here which I think is kind of related to what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372340/prevent-screen-flickering-when-opening-a-second-workbook-same-instance/42373829#42373829

Comment: Implemented it as suggested. First of all thank you very much. When going back to showing the screen, i get the same effect as previously when I make the window visible before setting ScreenUpdating back to True and a different kind (like a single, fullscreen flash) of effect when doing it the other way around. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The observation that it transitions without any visible effect after some time of not using the design switch might be something? Maybe something memory or cache related?